# Filtering the ListView in Fragments does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, filtering

In my Project I have 4 ListViews. 2 ListViews are in Activities and the other 2 ListViews are in Fragments. After setTextFilterEnabled(true), the Filtering only worked in the first Activity.. after some searching on the Web I got the **problem** that  the other Lists did not have Focus, so the Filtering was not Enabled.. Now it works on both Activities but not in my Fragments :(..

Does someone have an idea?

Here are some code snippets..

```
    NCViewPagerAdapter myAdapter = new NCViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int pos)
        {
            switch (pos)
            {
                case PAGE_MEKA:
                {
                    //Cause to Enable Filtering the View have to get Focus..
                    ListView lv = (ListView) ctx.findViewById(R.id.listMekaForNC);
                    lv.requestFocus();
                }
                case PAGE_SCHLAG_KOMB:
                {
                    ListView lv = (ListView) ctx.findViewById(R.id.listViewSchlag);
                    lv.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
```

and

```
    ListView lw = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewSchlag);
    List<Nutzungscode> schlaege = Data.getService().getSchlagKombinationen(nc.getID());
    lw.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.mylistitem, schlaege,Nutzungscode.class,new String[]{"getID","getName"}));
    lw.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: -.- forgot to use "break;" in the switch statement..